# How to hide Close,Minimize and Maximize buttons and the surrounding edges in awesomium application?

Tags: c++, awesomium

Is it possible to hide the native close,maximize and minimize button and the surrounding edges of the window that holdes an awesomium application..

[image]

I am looking for a way to design nice close,maximize and minimize button within the html document will do the function of the native buttons to be hidden.

**here are my c++ codes**

```
// Inherited from Application::Listener
  virtual void OnLoaded() {
    view_ = View::Create(500, 300);

    WebURL url(WSLit("file:///C:/Users/awesomium/Documents/app.html"));
    view_->web_view()->LoadURL(url);
  }
```

**contents of my html file is below**

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("You are running Awesomium " + awesomium.version);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: I am pretty new to awesomium and c++ (in a sense)..making this simple will be great!.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You control the traits of the created Windows window by setting the dwStyle property in the call to CreateWindow.

I used the Awesomium Tutorial 2 (http://wiki.awesomium.com/tutorials/tutorial-2-displaying-your-first-page.html)

Locate the ViewWin(int width, int height) constructor and edit the call to the CreateWindow. The following example creates a window with no borders nor a caption.

```
hwnd_ = CreateWindow(
          szWindowClass,
          szTitle,
          WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU,
          CW_USEDEFAULT,
          CW_USEDEFAULT,
          width + 20,
          height + 40, 
          NULL,
          NULL,
          hInstance,
          NULL);
```

When I tried it I got a problem with the WndProc being called pre-maturely (the view-pointer still NULL) so I added a quick fix to make the application run.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

...

case WM_SIZE:
  if (view == NULL) return 0; // Quick fix to not call view until it is fully initialized
  view->web_view()->Resize(LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam));
break;

...
```

This may not be the way to go and you can probably figure something better out? The created window looks like the following:

[image: Awesomium "Hello World" with no caption nor borders]

I hope this will get you on track to get your application to work as you like it to?

Comment: Hagdahi Thanks Dude...After I upgraded my kernel..awesomium failed to start.....I browsed the web and found there is a bug running awesomium webkit on linux with kernels>3.0..So I did not get to test this after upgrading..I'll accept your efforts seeing the snapshot....:D

Comment: Hi! You are on Linux? Sorry, I have to admit my example is for Windows as your example looked very much like a Windows window? The basic idea still holds though but you have to read the definition of your Linux platform windows creation call. I'll see if I get around to find a Linux Platform answer for you but I can't give you any promises.

Comment: @ Kjell-Olov Högdahl...I am on linux....sure whenever you have tested on linux just add it in your answer.. thanks